# ProxyPass on httpd breaking encoding

Tags: reverse-proxy, httpd, encoding, proxypass, charset

We are sending content with multibyte character data to proxypass, which is converting the characters to %uFFFD when it hits our database.

How do i prevent httpd from messing with the encoding like this?

Comment: Is it the content or the request URL that is doing this?

Comment: It is the content that is being altered

Comment: Just to be clear, the request headers and/or POST or PUT data are being mangled?  GET requests use the URL for variables.

Comment: POST data is getting changed